# How to build specific folder in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a folder myApp1 and pom.xml is lying inside myApp1. Here is the hirerchy of myApp1

```
myAppl1
  |--src
       |--main
             |--java 
               (Java Source Code)
             |--resources
               some xml files and doc files 
  |--pom.xml
```

Now if i do mvn package it build all the folders and makes jar files(basically it  puts also all the files under resources folder in jar file).

What i want is to build the files under java folder only which does not have any dependency on resources folder(java files dependencies are mentioned in POM file which are jars in repository).

I am not sure how we can build the specific folder in maven. I tried this mvn install -pl src\main\java -am but says Could not find the selected project in the reactor?

**EDIT** This is how i had put it in pom.xml before

```
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
<plugin> 
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version> 
        <configuration> 
            <verbose>true</verbose> 
            <excludes> 
                <exclude>resources/*</exclude> 
                <exclude>webapp/*</exclude>                     
            </excludes> 
        </configuration> 
</plugin> 
</plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
```

But i get [ERROR]     Malformed POM C:\myProject\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'pluginMana
gement' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n\r\n  
... @55:21)  @ C:\myProject\pom.xml, line 55, column 21 -> [Help 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `maven-jar-plugin` and configure it to exclude the files or directories which you do not want to include it in your JAR. Also, check out its [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) on Maven site. Following is a sample configuration for `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
    <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>properties/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>spring</exclude>
                    <exclude>spring/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     ...
     </plugins>
     ...
     </build>
```

Comment: Jugual could you clarify on error in my edit section. Thanks in advance

Comment: plugins tag should be inside build element and not pluginManagement. Please refer to the modified snippet in the answer.

Comment: hey jugal thanks but still it  includes the files under resources and webapp folder. ialso tried like this <exclude>**/resources/*</exclude>   where resources is the folder name

Comment: Well you have to explicitly specify all the files under resources directory. For instance, if you have properties directory and logback.xml file inside your resources directory and if you dont want to include any of the contents inside this directory, then you have to add some thing like this:       <exclude>properties</exclude>      <exclude>properties/*</exclude>       <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>

Comment: Jugal if i give <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>    it works. But ihink excluding folders are not suppoerted

Comment: Yeah, not directly. As I said, if you want to exclude properties directory inside the resources, then you have to add following two exclude entries: <exclude>properties</exclude> <exclude>properties/*</exclude>

Answer (score 2):

You must put the *maven-jar-plugin* declaration in the *< build >* section rather than in *< pluginManagement >*.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a "don't do this" kind of answer.

Maven expects the resources to be files that have to end up in your artifact, that's what resources are for. If you have other files they really should be put somewhere else.

Having said that, it is possible to confuse the heck of everyone expecting the conventional behaviour and to tell maven that files in src/main/resources are in fact not resources.

To do that say in your POM build section

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Resource copying is handled by the [maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/), so its documentation is worth a look for resources related trouble.

Answer (score 1):

for files that shouldn't be copied into the artifact file you can use the projects src/main/config directory, which fullfills also the maven naming conventions.

in my special case I use this directory for storing binary sources like .exe files aso. that get zipped by the assembly plugin and are deployed to my repository as zip and bin which works well and seems like a clean workflow.